# Pigmentation of aromates

Tags: aromatic-compounds, color

So, they try to color naftalene, nitrobenzeen and benzene. Only one of them colors. They can say with certainty that this is nitrobenzeen. Right/wrong and why?
Sorry if my English isn't that great, not my native language!!
Thanks a lot x

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed nitrobenzene.

You really should look at the compounds, literally, because chemistry is ultimately an experimental science.

That being so, you can still note that the conjugated nitro group with its electronegative atoms gives relatively low-lying vacant orbitals into which electrons can be excited.  These orbitals can be accessed by absorbing short wavelength (violet/blue) visible light leading to a yellow color.